# How to hide mui multiselect selected options in the select field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I'm using MUI multiselect for selecting multiple options from dropdown. But the problem is I don't want to show the selected option in the dropdown field. How can I hide that selected options?
Here is what I'm getting but I don't want to show the selected options there.
[image]

Comment: what do you want to display there. I appreciate if you provide code or stackblitz example

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove label from the Select props. Or you need to manage renderValue prop to show empty text. It will be helpful if you provide your code snippet here.Then I can sort out your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I changed the way of showing select options now.

Comment: Hi, Mohd Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you see the question is not clear, It is better to ask for more details via comment first and post an answer when you surely understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

In this example, the renderValue prop of Material-UI's Select component is customized to dynamically render the selected options. If an option has isSelected set to true, it is hidden, otherwise, it is displayed.

```
<Select
  multiple
  renderValue={(selected) => (
    <div>
      {selected.map((option) => (
        option.isSelected && '' ))}
    </div>
  )}
  // ... other MultiSelect props
/>
```